# Alternatives to WebLogic Integration

Tags: java, weblogic

Our company uses WLI primarily as an interface between a web application, and an SAP back-end.  WLI is outdated, and we want to use an open-source replacement for it.  Can someone suggest some products that could be used to replace WLI with similar functionality?

Comment: They say the best replacement option for WebLogic is Websphere, Do watch this link for more info [Alternatives for WebLogic](http://dooblet.com/alternative-to-weblogic).  Regards

Answer (score 0):

The natural path would be a migration to BPEL (Oracle SOA Suite), but that doesn't fit your open source needs. 
 Maybe Spring Integration will of your something, but nothing like WLI JDP or other infrastructure services (like event generators, process status report) that WLI offers.  Also, you may notice some limitations on the cluster side...